# A race condition in a custom implementation of recursive mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stl, race-condition

**UPD**: It seems that the problem which I explain below is non-existent. I cannot reproduce it in a week already, I started suspecting that it was caused by some bugs in a compiler or corrupted memory because it is not reproducing anymore.

---

I tried to implement my own recursive mutex in C++, but for some reason, it fails. I tried to debug it, but I stuck. (I know that there are recursive mutex in std, but I need a custom implementation in a project where STL is not available; this implementation was just a check of an idea). I haven't thought about efficiency yet, but I don't understand why my straightforward implementation doesn't work.

First of all, here's the implementation of the RecursiveMutex:

```
class RecursiveMutex
{
    std::mutex critical_section;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::thread::id id;
    int recursive_calls = 0;

public:
    void lock() {
        auto thread = std::this_thread::get_id();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(critical_section);

        cv.wait( lock, [this, thread]() {
            return id == thread || recursive_calls == 0;
        });

        ++recursive_calls;
        id = thread;
    }

    void unlock() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock( critical_section );
        --recursive_calls;
        if( recursive_calls == 0 ) {
            lock.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    }
};
```

The failing test is straightforward, it just runs two threads, both of them are locking and unlocking the same mutex (the recursive nature of the mutex is not tested here). Here it is:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

void initThreads( int num_of_threads, std::function<void()> func )
{
    threads.resize( num_of_threads );
    for( auto& thread : threads )
    {
        thread = std::thread( func );
    }
}

void waitThreads()
{
    for( auto& thread : threads )
    {
        thread.join();
    }
}

void test () {
    RecursiveMutex mutex;

    while (true) {
        int count = 0;
        initThreads(2, [&mutex] () {
            for( int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i ) {
                try {
                    mutex.lock();
                    ++count;
                    mutex.unlock();
                }
                catch (...) {
                    // Extremely rarely.
                    // Exception is "Operation not permited"
                    assert(false);
                }
            }
        });

        waitThreads();
        // Happens often
        assert(count == 200000);
    }  
}
```

In this code I have two kinds of errors:

1. Extremely rarely I get an exception in `RecursiveMutex::lock()` which contains message "Operation not permitted" and is thrown from `cv.wait`.  As far as I understand, this exception is thrown when `wait` is called on a mutex which is not owned by the thread. At the same time, I lock it just above calling the `wait` so this cannot be the case.
2. In most situations I just get a message into console "terminate called without an active exception".

My main question is what the bug is, but I'll also be happy to know how to debug and provoke race condition in such a code in general.

P.S. I use Desktop Qt 5.4.2 MinGW 32 bit.

Comment: You should release your lock before you notify.

Comment: I tried doing that (at least in lock method), but it doesn't fix the problem).

Comment: FYI: The lack of activity is likely not due to people not looking at it; I certainly spent some time. I just couldn't find any issues with your code. Maybe has something to do with your OS/implementation of std library.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `id==thread` condition?

Comment: I've initially implemented it based on other custom library (which is not available outside our company) and I've found that it doesn't work. I wasn't sure that the mistake is in the algorithm and not in the library so I reimplemented it in STL just to check it and I managed to catch the exception several times.

Comment: Comparison of thread is used to make sure that if the mutex is locked in other thread, the lock method doesn't return.

Comment: `cv.notify_all()` call in `lock()` is pointless, it can't possibly wake any thread. It should be harmless though.

Comment: Ok, I improved the code and the test, so now the problem with the code can be reproduced easily (although it is yet not clear for me, I'm working on this).

Comment: I cannot reproduce anything or find any problem with the code.

Comment: What happens if more than one thread is waiting in `cv.wait()` and the thread holding the lock frees it?  In other words, run 3 or more threads instead of two.  Also, what happens if a thread that *doesn't* hold the lock calls `unlock()`?  It looks like a thread can call `unlock()` and decrement  `recursive_calls` without holding the lock itself.